# Sort list of page templates a-z?

Tags: template-tags

In the code below, it possible to sort the results alphabetically - and if so what changes do I need?

```
<?php 
$templates = get_page_templates();
foreach ( $templates as $template_name => $template_filename ) {
echo "$template_name ($template_filename)<br />";
}
?>
```

If that code can't be adapted, what's an alternative query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) function to sort the array of `$templates = get_page_templates();`. So the full code will be-

```
<?php
$templates = get_page_templates();
// Sort based on key
ksort($templates);
foreach ( $templates as $template_name => $template_filename ) {
    echo "$template_name ($template_filename)<br />";
}
?>
```

Also see [`asort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) if you need.

Comment: @ the_dramatist ... Thanks. I wasn't aware of ksort/asort/krsort.